# Remove space between empty quotes in csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell-5.0

I have a csv file with many empty quotes and I want to remove them using powershell. Tried various solutions but it didn't work.
Sample data :" ","abc","","   ","123"
Expected output:,"abc",,"123"

Answer (score 0):

csv generally has headers and comma separated values below. For this reason, removing the empty strings would break a traditional csv. This can be done though.

```
$sampleData = " ,  , abc, , , , 123"

#split it

$sampleSplit = $sampleData.Split(',')

#re join it

$sampleOutput = [string]::Join(',', ($sampleSplit | Where { $_.Trim() -ne [String]::Empty }))


Write-Host "$sampleData is now $sampleOutput"
```

This can be simplified but I separated it for readability.